# Change Safari address plus [+] button default action

Tags: safari

The default action of the plus [+] button next to the URL is to save it to the Reading List. I care not for this list. I want to save it to my bookmarks because I have it organised into folders neatly there.

I know you can hold on to it and click the bookmarks button, but that just adds another second or 2 to my workflow.

Is there anyway to change the default action of this button?